# how to integrate this Function in matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I'm new on matlab.

How can I integrate this line of code ? ?

```
p2= polyfit(x,y,length(x));
from= x(1);
to= x(length(x));
```

I need the integration of `p2`.

I tried a lot with the Integration function:

```
 value = integral(p2,from,to);
```

but I got

> Error using integral (line 82) First input argument must be a function
>   handle.

```
Error in poly_integral (line 5)
 value = integral(p2,from,to);
```

Comment: pass the function `y` in rather than the coefficients of `y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `p2`, in your code, is not a function. It is just a vector of coefficients. The first argument for `integral` needs to be handle to the function that you want to integrate.

Judging from your code, it seems that you would want to define a function that evaluates the polynomial `p2`. If so, you could do something like the following example:

```
% take an example set of x and y 
x = linspace(0, pi, 1000); % uniform samples between 0 to pi
y = sin(x); % assume, for sake of example, output is sine function of input

% polynomial fit
p2 = polyfit(x,y,4); % 4th order polynomial
% Note that, in general, the order should be much smaller than length(x).
% So you probably should review this part of your code as well.

% define a function to evaluate the polynomial
fn = @(x) polyval(p2, x);
% this means: fn(x0) is same as polyval(p2, x0)

% compute integral
value = integral(fn,x(1),x(end));
```

Comment: thank you so much , one more thing you said -
the order should be much smaller than length(x).
actually as our instructor order he wrote :
 fit the data to a polynomial of degree n where n is the number of elements of x, 
did he mean something else or he may be wrong ?

Comment: @programmer: Assuming `n = length(x)`, a polynomial of degree `n-1` is sufficient to get an exact fit between `fn(x)` and `y`, no matter what `y` you choose. So, in my opinion, there is no good reason to ever fit a polynomial of degree `n` or higher (except experimentation, may be).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`polyint`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyint.html) function to get the polynomial coefficients for exact integration of the polynomial:

```
p2  = polyfit(x,y,length(x));
int = diff(polyval(polyint(p2),x([1 end])));
```